# Calling setSelected method in getView method of ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on a test application in which people can see questions to solve. On the questions page, there is a `TextView` to show the question, a `ListView` to show the options and two buttons for going back and forth between questions.

I am using `SparseArray` to associate the selected option position in the `ListView` to question location that is coming from `mAllQuestions` of type `List<Question>`.

I am also using an AnswerModel looks like this:

```
public class AnswerModel
{
    public String mAnswerText;
    public boolean mIsSelected;
    public AnswerModel(String answerText)
    {
        mAnswerText = answerText;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return mAnswerText; 
    }
}
```

and I use `AnswerModel` to create an `ArrayAdapter` and it looks like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<AnswerModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AnswerModel>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1)
{
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);;
        AnswerModel model = getItem(position);
        // This is where it does not work.
        v.setSelected(model.isSelected);
        return v;
    }
}
```

and after I create my `ArrayAdapter` I execute the following code:

```
List<Answer> answers = getAnswersByQuestionLocation(questionLocation);
for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++)
{
    answerAdapter.add(new AnswerModel(mOptionLetters[i] +". "+ answers.get(i).getAnswerText()));
}
```

and the code above adds the items to the `ArrayAdapter`. When a click happens on the ListView, I am putting the selected option position and question position to the `SparseArray` typed `mAnswerLocationByQuestionLocation` and **I use it to update the selected option background**.

```
if (mAnswerLocationByQuestionLocation.indexOfKey(questionLocation) > -1)
    {
        MyModel model = (MyModel)mAnswerList.getItemAtPosition(questionLocation);
        model.isSelected= true;
        answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

So the problem is v.setSelected doesn't change the background color of the selected item in the `ListView`. **I debugged the application and all `isSelected` property works and it actually passes `true` to `v.setSelected(model.isSelected)` method call.**

I have tried many ways as follows but they didn't work:

1. Calling `refreshDrawableState()` on `ListView` as well `v`.
2. I called `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate()` not working.
3. I called `v.post(new Runnable())` and running `v.setSelected(model.isSelected)`
4. I have a drawable selector which sets selected state background color but no luck.

If you ask me why I just don't change the background color of `v` by saying `v.setBackgroundColor` which does actually work but it causes another problem. When I select another item from the list, it remains highlighted and this leads to two highlighted item in the single option choice list. I can call `setBackgroundColor(...Color.white)` of all the items in `setOnItemClick` event handler of `ListView` but when I do that, clicking on an item later doesn't make the item highlighted. It is like a rabbit hole.

Any ideas?

Comment: What view you are using like CheckBox or RadioButton??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `listView.setItemChecked(position, true)` if you'd like the item to show as selected along with setting your `ListView` selection mode to either `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` or `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` depending on if you want to show one or more than one item selected at once.

**Update from OP:**

I am marking your answer because actually this answer work after I took the following path:

In the `getView()` method of `ArrayAdapter`, I am accessing `ListView` variable and call its `setItemChecked()` method with appropriate parameters.

So it looks like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    AnswerModel model = getItem(position);
    mAnswerList.setItemChecked(position, model.isSelected);
    return v;
}
```

but this approach caused another problem so I had to update `onItemClick` event handler of `ListView` like following:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id)
{
    setAnswerModel(mCurrentQuestionLocation, false);
    mAnswerLocationByQuestionLocation.put(mCurrentQuestionLocation,
            position);
    setAnswerModel(mCurrentQuestionLocation, true);
    mAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

which invokes `setAnswerModel` method which looks like this:

```
private void setAnswerModel(int questionLocation, boolean isSelected)
{
    if (mAnswerLocationByQuestionLocation.indexOfKey(questionLocation) > -1)
    {
        int answerLocation = mAnswerLocationByQuestionLocation
                .get(questionLocation);
        AnswerModel model = (AnswerModel) mAnswerAdapter.getItem(answerLocation);
        model.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In AnswerModel class **create getter setter methods for mIsSelected** variable too and check that in getView() of Adapter and then set appropriately that should work.

Comment: How do you think it is different than what I am doing in my code? Instead of getters and setters, I am directly setting the member itself which is enough since I don't need encapsulation here.

Comment: How will you distinguish between two different AnswerModels mIsSelected variable and why u created then into AnswerModel class there is no necessity if you think of using another way like u have done above right??